# Push notifications with sockets for desktop WPF aplication (No Win8 App)

Tags: sockets, c#-4.0, .net-3.5, push-notification, desktop-application

I'm trying to get into an implementation of some kind of push notification for a Windows WPF client application and a java backed server.

The idea is to avoid as much as possible polling the server, so I thought to implement it with sockets and messages, and relying in some easy pulling solution in case a socket connection could not be done, (Firewalls, etc).
In the other hand is important that the data traveling get encrypted.

So I have a couple of question/"request for opinions" more related with the WPF client:

1. Perhaps already exist some solution for that, any tips?
2. Could be good to think in some SSL sockets connections for that?
3. If 2 is OK, there is some native solution for secure sockets in .net or any library?
4. If sockets solutions is an option, I guess i need to go through port 443 and by the way it will avoid many problems with firewalls and so on, am i right?

I know there is many question but all are related to the same problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

1. http://clientengine.codeplex.com/
2. Yes, SSL is good if you need to keep the data secure during transfer
3. Yes, http://clientengine.codeplex.com/ indicates it supports SSL/TLS
4. Well, it depends on whether you are controlling the server or not. If you have control over it you can use whatever port you want.